# Writing a QNetworkReply to a file

Tags: c++, qt

I'm downloading a file using QNetworkAccessManager::get but unlike QHttp::get there's no built-in way to directly write the response to a different QIODevice.

The easiest way would be to do something like this:

```
QIODevice* device;

QNetworkReply* reply = manager.get(url);
connect(reply, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(newData()));
```

and then in newData slot:

```
device->write(reply->readAll());
```

But I'm not sure if this is the right way, maybe I missed something.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That looks correct. I would use the lower-level forms of `read()` and `write()`, not the `QByteArray` ones, which do not properly support error handling, but other than that, it looks fine.

Are you having problems with it?

Comment: I haven't ran into any problems so far but I'm worried that if I have a big amount of parallel downloads, this whole operation might cause a bottle neck.

Comment: Unlikely, but possible. You can optimize by using a stack `char buffer[4098]` to avoid the `malloc()s` involved in the `QByteArray` creation. There's also `QVarLengthArray`.

Comment: yeah that's what I did with the local char array. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Better use the finished signal to read all the contents at the end of the download process. An example (remove the event loop and use a new slot to make it asynchronous):

```
    QNetworkAccessManager manager;
    QEventLoop loop;
    QNetworkReply *reply = manager.get( request );
    QObject::connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()), &loop, SLOT(quit()));

    loop.exec();

    QFile file( "YOUR FILE" );
    file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    file.write(reply->readAll());

    delete reply;
```

Comment: this can cause some serious memory/performance issues when dealing with large requests