# how to get response in QtWebKit

Tags: qtwebkit

im beginner with QtWebKit i build simple web frame that loaded page ( server side ) 
and when from this page i submit data i like to catch the response string from the server in the c++ side 
how can i do that ?

Comment: Start by using more punctuation marks and fewer blanks. Would improve readability and comprehensibility.

Answer (score 8):

I tinkered around with Qt (which I'm new to) and found a way to catch all resources downloaded by WebKit. Here's how:

1) Create your own subclass of QNetworkAccessManager

2) In your derived class, override virtual function createRequest

3) Call base class implementation to get the response object. After that you can look at 
the URL (or other parameters) and determine whether you need to capture that particular resource or not

4) if you do - connect readyRead signal to some slot that will capture the data

5) in that slot call peek function to read data so that WebKit will get the data also

6) After creating QWebPage object, call setNetworkAccessManager and pass a newly created instance of your subclass from step 1)

That's it - enjoy!

Comment: nice thing about this approach is that it seems that it takes care of Content-Encoding: gzip and deflate at that point so you don't need to decompress data yourself

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`QNetworkReply`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qnetworkreply.html) class for it. [`QWebPage`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qwebpage.html) instances have [`networkAccessManager()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qwebpage.html#networkAccessManager) method that returns a [`QNetworkAccessManager`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qnetworkaccessmanager.html) instance capable of sending requests and receiving responses.

You need to look for its [`finished`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qnetworkaccessmanager.html#finished) signal.

`void QNetworkAccessManager::finished ( QNetworkReply * reply )`

> This signal is emitted whenever a
>   pending network reply is finished. The
>   reply parameter will contain a pointer
>   to the reply that has just finished.

[`QNetworkReply`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qnetworkreply.html) in its turn is an inheritor of [`QIODevice`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qiodevice.html) therefore you are able to call its [`readAll()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qiodevice.html#readAll) method in order to receive the response data.

You may also find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1205419/writing-a-qnetworkreply-to-a-file) question useful.

Comment: I want to do the exact same thing and this method doesn't seem to work: when finished signal is emitted, WebKit already read all data from the reply object so it's just not there.