# PyQt4 QWebView external resource content

Tags: python, qt, webkit, qtwebkit

```
class Browser(QWebView):
    def __init__(self):
        QWebView.__init__(self)
        self.loadFinished.connect(self._result_available)
        self.loadStarted.connect(self._load_started)
        self.page().frameCreated.connect(self.onFrame)
    # ...     

browser = Browser()
browser.setHtml('<html>...</html>', baseUrl=QUrl('http://www.google.com/'))
```

After that, i need to catch content of all external resources loaded by **QWebView**. I need to get content of all CSS/Javascript files. How can i do that ? Related questions: [question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1205419/writing-a-qnetworkreply-to-a-file), [question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2426053/how-to-get-response-in-qtwebkit)

I know i need to use [QNetworkAccessManager](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qnetworkaccessmanager.html) somehow, but i don't have any example to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to make custom **QNetworkReply** class and get results in **readyRead** event results.